# How can I send some String value from one class to another class

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, apache-camel

In my Architecture `Activemq` getting messages from `Sql Server Database` whenever `DB`changes.

We written 3 consumer files name are `FirstConsumer.java,SecondConsumer.java and ThirdConsumer.java` for processing messages using `Spring` framework.

so far, we written `*MiddileWare.java` files for every consumer files.in the following way.

[image]
My Business code is written in `MessageProcessing.java`.for your understanding I posted `firstConsumer.java` coressponding files codes.

FirstConsumer.java :

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class FirstConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ApplicationContext contextObject=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
        //Forwarding cursor to ConsumersMiddileWare class using CamelContext
        CamelContext camelObject=contextObject.getBean("activeContext1", CamelContext.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
}
```

FirstMiddileWare.java :

```
 import org.apache.camel.spring.SpringRouteBuilder;
 public class ConsumersMiddileWare2 extends SpringRouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    VariablesDeclarations vd=lookup("amqURL",VariablesDeclarations.class);
    from(vd.getAmqLink()).transacted().to("bean:msgPro1?Method=Processor1");
}
 }
```

MessageProcessing.java :

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
public class MessageProcessing{
 public void MessageProcessing(Exchange exe,String exeFilepath) {
    //Business Code Here
  }
 public void Processor1(Exchange exe) {
    MessageProcessing processorObject=new MessageProcessing();
    processorObject.MessageProcessing(exe,"Rod1");
}
public void Processor2(Exchange exe) {
    MessageProcessing processorObject=new MessageProcessing();
    processorObject.MessageProcessing(exe,"Rod2");
}
}
```

Spring configuration xml file name as `bean.xml` with all consumer configurations.

bean.xml :

```
<!--FirstConsumer-->
<camelContext id="activeContext1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="activeMQRouter1" />
</camelContext>
<!--SecondConsumer-->
<camelContext id="activeContext2" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="activeMQRouter2" />
</camelContext>
<!--ThirdConsumer-->
<camelContext id="activeContext3" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="activeMQRouter3" />
</camelContext>
<!--FirstConsumer-->
<bean id="activeMQRouter1" class="ActivemqPackage.FirstMiddileWare"/>
<!--SecondConsumer-->
<bean id="activeMQRouter2" class="ActivemqPackage.SecondMiddileWare"/>
<!--ThirdConsumer-->
<bean id="activeMQRouter3" class="ActivemqPackage.ThirdMiddileWare"/>
```

so far we followed in above way. It's working fine. Now I am trying to Implement following way.

[image]

Following code was differnce code between First,Second,Third Middileware files.

SecondMiddileWare.java

```
  from(vd.getAmqLink()).transacted().to("bean:msgPro1?Method=Processor2");
```

ThirdMiddileWare.java :

```
  from(vd.getAmqLink()).transacted().to("bean:msgPro1?Method=Processor3");
```

I stuck in making of `ConsumerMiddileWare.java` file for all Consumer files.

If you not understand, let me know I will edit my question.

My Idea:

If we send any `String` format value from Consumer(`FirstConsumer.java,...`) file to MiddileWare(FirstMiddileWare.java,...).

Based on that value, I will call that corresponding process(`Process1,..`)method.

Thanks

Comment: I dont think people understand your question, can you explain better?

Comment: @ClausIbsen I modified my question. can you check it once.If you not understand let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things...

- just can you a [content based router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) to route messages to the correct processor/method based on the 'String' value
- you don't need separate CamelContexts for each RouteBuilder or even separate RouteBuilders for each route...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes I don't need to create separate RouteBuilders for each route.I configured all Routes in single `CamelContext` tag.Know I don't want to create `SecondConsumers.java,ThirdConsumer.java and ConsumerMiddileWare.java`.

Comment: if you just bootstrap your camelContext.xml with a Sprint context, then you won't need any of those classes, just start the context and let your routes setup on their own...not sure what you are trying to do otherwise